# 20.04 firewall conundrum

Tags: networking, firewall, nfs

I'm trying to share files on home network between two linux machines: host-A is Ubuntu 20.04, host-B is Red Hat. Samba worked well until distr. upgrade to 20.04. Now cifs mount from host-B reports "No route to host". Typical and obvious remedies don't work. `sudo ufw status` shows a bunch of ports allowed. I can ping host-A or ping ip of host-A, but cannot connect with gigolo or other smb protocol. Then I tried to set up nfs - same problem. Testing connection from host-B:

```
nmap host-A
```

returns `22   tcp   open ssh` but when I do

```
ssh host-A:22
```

I get " Could not resolve host... Name or service not known"
Same with ip address instead of host name.

I know smb or nfs does not use port 22, the above is only to demonstrate that something in firewall is not working the way I understand it should.

I've searched answers but so far this remains a conundrum for me. I must be doing something wrong or missing something. To me it looks like my Ubuntu 20,04 (host-A) can only react to ping in my home network (wireless, 192.168.0.0).

CORRECTION: my test with ssh was incorrectly described. The correct command was `ssh host-A`, and host-A did in fact recognize the connection attempt, registered host-B. Then `ssh user@host-A` did connect after entering user password. Then I had terminal access to host-A on the host-B machine. Nevertheless, neither samba nor nfs file sharing succeeded despite having ports allowed in ufw. Same error as in my original posting.

ADDITIONAL info based on Answer 1:
Outputs of host command on local network targeting Host-B

```
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ host Host-B
Host Host-B not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ host 192.168.nnn.mmm
mmm.nnn.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer Host-B.
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$
```

If I do vpn on Host-B where it is on mydomain.com

```
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ host Host-B.mydomain.com
Host-B.mydomain.com has address xxx.pub.lic.ip
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$
```

Samba related command outputs:

```
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ sudo smbstatus
[sudo] password for user: 

Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No locked files

user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ findsmb

                            *=DMB
                            +=LMB
IP ADDR         NETBIOS NAME     WORKGROUP/OS/VERSION 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$ smbtree
user@Host-A:~/Desktop$
```

Same in Host-B
[userB@Host-B Desktop]$ smbstatus

```
Samba version 3.6.23-53.el6_10
PID     Username      Group         Machine                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------

No locked files

[userB@Host-B Desktop]$ findsmb

                                *=DMB
                                +=LMB
IP ADDR         NETBIOS NAME     WORKGROUP/OS/VERSION 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.nnn.mmm   CENTOS         [AB] [Unix] [Samba 3.6.23-53.el6_10]
[userB@Host-B Desktop]$ smbtree
Enter userB's password: 
[userB@Host-B Desktop]$
```

More info:
Apparently Host-B finds itself in samba and Host-A does not. However, in Host-A (the Ubuntu machine) Browse Network in Thunar does display the netbios name of itself, defined in smb.conf. Yet findsmb command cannot find itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Canonical has disabled SMB1 for security reasons. SMB2/SMB3 still works.

`smbtree` command also no longer works.

**Either...**

Use //server/pathname or //IP/pathname when using the **Connect to Server**, or in your /etc/fstab

**or**

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf, and add this to the Network section, and restart smbd and nmbd...

```
# allow SMB1
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
```

Use the `testparm` command to confirm that your smb.conf file is correct.

Comment: Thx for your thought. I already had the NT1 part but no lmhosts and wins. I also had client lanman auth = yes, but commented it out and made my conf the same as suggested. After that testparm OK, restarted service. However - still the same. server/path gives No route error, IP/path gives time out error. Something else must be screwed up on my system. At anyrate, I prefer nfs method because the only computers I have on my home lan are linux and smart phones. I can use ftp for the smart phones and USB stick for file sharing until nfs works.

Comment: @Janos Do you also have other network problems. Can you `host www.ebay.com` and `ping www.google.com`?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a network problem. Yes, both of your commands work fine. The good news is that I can do sftp sessions both ways, also with gui file managers, although host-A can only connect with ip, not with name. So the conundrum persists: sftp works but nfs or samba won't. I'm all set with sftp, but still curious what's goin' on.

Comment: @Janos *"host-A can only connect with ip, not with name"* is the name in /etc/hosts? What does `sudo smbstatus` show? Does it work with the firewall turned off? If you do `//hostname.local/pathname` in **Connect to Server**, does that work? Does `findsmb` and `smbtree` work? Edit those outputs into your question, not into the comments please.

Comment: "Edit those outputs" - done. Also included varoius outputs of `host` command. When I try connect to Server on Host-B the error is "Failed to retrieve share list from server"

Comment: @Janos It looks like SMB1 isn't working on Host-A. You did the mods to smb.conf and restarted smbd and nmbd, yes? Do the smbstatus/findsmb/smbtree commands work on Host-B?

Comment: smbstatus does work on Host-B indicating version 3.6.23 The other two commends don't exist. And YES to all others.

Comment: @Janos You need to install `smbclient`... then you'll get findsmb/smbtree.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I did install it on Host-B and edited more info into my question

Comment: @Janos  Host-A, the Ubuntu machine, isn't finding any DMB/LMB or itself. Host-B, the Centos machine, running a different version of Samba, also isn't finding any DMB/LMB. Do you have any other Samba shares or DMB/LMB masters on the network?

Comment: No. Just these two and no Windows machines. I access occasionally android smart phones on same network with Filezilla. My home network IPs are dhcp assigned; may change IP if lease expires.

Comment: @Janos  In smb.conf, what is `#   wins support = no` set to?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I lost my original distribution smb.conf. My customized file (uncommented, etc) worked well with 18.04 and 16.04 Ubuntu. The bottom line: there is no

Comment: @Janos Get a copy at /usr/share/samba/smb.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123004/discussion-between-janos-and-heynnema).